# How to get all the 'content' values in the following list by iterating over the list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
    [
      { u'content': u'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', 
        u'filename': u'test2.pdf'},

      { u'content': u'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',
        u'filename': u'test.jpg'}
     ]
```

If the list contains N items, How can I retrive the content part in a separate list like

```
content_list = ['JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iag' ,'4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBqRXhpZgAATU0A', '4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBqRXhpZgAATU0A' ]
```

Comment: try like : List<MyObject> ppl2 = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyObject[].class));

Comment: Why did you use mapper to retrieve the value of "json" key again? You can just use `JsonNode source = input.get("json")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

The code in your case would be similar to this:

```
array = [ ... ] # Your initial array
content_array = [item.get("content") for item in array]
```